# Find out exact MS Software product name using version info

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, version

I need to know the product name based on a version number for MS office products. Ive looked everywhere but cannot find a list of versions together with the exact product name. There are some lists specifying what program it relates to but not the exact product.

For eg. Microsoft Office Visio 2010 12.0.4518.1014

Is that version for Visio Standard or Professional? I would have thought there would have been a list or program which could tell you the exact product name based on the version.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you need to use the version number?  You can find which edition of Visio is installed in Add/Remove Programs, AKA Programs and Features, AKA `appwiz.cpl`.

The screenshot below shows the Premium edition, which is the highest grade - above Standard or Professional.

[image]

In any case, the version number alone won't help you.  This will be the same across all editions of Visio, and will change as updates are released.  If you can't, for some reason, directly observe the name of the installed edition, the next most useful piece of data would be the product key or product ID.  There are probably several tools online that can analyze those and tell you which eidition they map to.

Comment: ok thanks for that, ill have to find another way. Basically im pulling all the version information from Bigfix which contains thousands of PC records. As part of a software audit, we are trying to identify what product each PC has and we thought we could do it by version info but obviously not.

Comment: @Michael If Bigfix can do custom Registry queries, find out what keys contain the Product ID and you should have the information you need.  Just bang the list of Product IDs from your system against a reference that maps Product IDs to actual edition names.